# What is an unflankable target as per Deadeye?

Tags: xcom-2

I understand what a flanked or unflanked target is, but what makes a target unflankable? Does it have to be surrounded by cover on all sides? I don't get it.

Comment: That typically refers to enemies that do not use cover. However, I'm not seeing any mention of this in the Deadeye description - it's aim penalty in exchange for bonus damage, no mention of cover or flanking. Are you using a mod? Or looking at a different skill?

Comment: @qazmlpok oh I am using RPGO, maybe it changed the description. The description says "Confers +15 Aim and +15 Crit against unflankable targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the specifics of RPGO, or the changes that may have been made, but I assume this definition hasn't changed.

Some enemies will never use cover and thus cannot be flanked. These enemies will not give bonus crit chance even when standing in the open.

In vanilla XCom2, these enemies are: Andromedon (and shell), Berserker, Chryssalids, Faceless, Sectopod, and Gatekeeper.

Flying enemies also do not give a flanking bonus despite being exposed; the game was classify this as "unflankable" as well.

The Lost are an exception. They never use cover, but do grant the usual bonuses for being exposed.

Comment: The enemy list is mostly from memory. I'm pretty sure none of those use cover, but I'm not positive. XCOM EU gave these unflankable enemies the "hardened" attribute, but it appears to be missing in XCOM 2.